# Mocha, integration JS tests and asynchronous IO

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mocha.js, fs

I need to create some files before integration test:

```
before(function(done) {
    fs.mkdir('tmp');
    fs.mkdir('tmp/css');
    fs.mkdir('tmp/js');
    fs.mkdir('tmp/lib');
    fs.open('tmp/index.htm', 'w');
    fs.open('tmp/some.js', 'w');
    fs.open('tmp/some.css', 'w');
    fs.open('tmp/css/main.css', 'w');
    fs.open('tmp/css/sub.css', 'w');
    fs.open('tmp/js/main.js', 'w');
    fs.open('tmp/lib/jquery.js', 'w');
    done();
});
```

The problem is, that I get:

```
fs: missing callback Error: ENOENT, mkdir 'tmp/css'
fs: missing callback Error: ENOENT, mkdir 'tmp/js'
fs: missing callback Error: ENOENT, mkdir 'tmp/lib'
fs: missing callback Error: ENOENT, open 'tmp/css/main.css'
fs: missing callback Error: ENOENT, open 'tmp/css/sub.css'
fs: missing callback Error: ENOENT, open 'tmp/js/main.js'
fs: missing callback Error: ENOENT, open 'tmp/lib/jquery.js'
```

I think the problem is, that it tries to open files synchronously before directories are created. I could use `fs.mkdirSync` and pass a callback to each, but then I have a problem with `done();`. How should this code look like if I want to have it done right way?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it is asynchronously trying to open files, and hitting done() before all the fs functions have returned.

Just change everything to use fs.mkdirSync and fs.openSync. Sync is for synchronous and so you won't need a callback; execution will just pause until fs returns. This would be terrible in a web server, where all other work would halt, but is fine in testing.